# What is the difference between Content-Type: application/json and Accept: application/json

Tags: rest, http

Can anyone explain what is the exact difference between -

```
1. Content-Type: application/json
2. Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Take a look at [difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Content-Type" indicates the format of the message body (either request or response).

"Accept" in a request indicates the preferred format for the response.

Comment: Is it for data validation?